# How to make datetime callable in python module?

Tags: django, python-datetime

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
start = datetime.now()
if datetime.now() - start() > timedelta(seconds=5):
```

'datetime.datetime' object is not callable

the problem in the 'if' string.
Thanks if you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You should not write parenthesis for the `start()`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start = datetime.now()
if datetime.now() - start > timedelta(seconds=5):
    # …
    pass
```

`start` is a `datetime` *object*, and it does not make much sense to perform a function call on a `datetime` object.